# Как скрыть маркеры с расстоянием для пешеходного мультимаршрута

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

Как найти все опции и их параметры для настройки мультимаршрута?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если кому-то поможет моё решение - ссылка на него: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/896407/yandex-maps-api-multiroute-pedestrian-Маркеры-с-расстоянием-как-их-удали/896565#896565

Answer (score 2):

По вашим вопросам [из документации](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/multiRouter.MultiRoute-docpage/?from=SO):

1. Кастомизация внешнего вида "нитки" мультимаршрута возможна аналогично настройке обычных точек и полилиний, т.к. мультимаршрут расширяет `IGeoObject`.

   Для указания опций используются [префиксы](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/multiRouter.MultiRoute-docpage?from=SO#param-options), которые указывают, какую часть маршрута нужно настроить. Доступные настройки каждого типа геометрий описаны в соответствующих разделах Справочника, вот, например, [для полилиний](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/Polyline-docpage/?from=SO).

   Вот [подробный пример](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/multiroute_view_options?from=SO), где показаны почти все доступные настройки.
2. Промежуточные точки бывают двух видов `wayPoint` (точка "заезда") и `viaPoint` (точка "привязки" маршрута), они отображаются по-разному и настраиваются отдельно друг от друга. В вашем примере стоит использовать via-точки - для них не будет отображаться расстояние до конца маршрута. Для этого укажите в параметрах мультимаршрута индексы всех точек кроме начала и конца маршрута:

   ```
   viaIndexes: [1,2,3...]
   ```
3. Для маршрутов на общественном транспорте есть возможность отключить маркеры пешеходных сегментов, используя опцию с префиксом:

   ```
   routeWalkMarkerVisible: false
   ```

   Поскольку ваш маршрут предполагает маленькие расстояния между точками, вы можете поробовать поменять тип маршрута на `masstransit` и добавить опцию выше.

Comment: вы даете пример и говорите что там почти все описано, генерирую ситуацию, мне нужно скрыть все точки кроме начала и конца, так вот, в документации найти НЕВОЗМОЖНО этого, так как нет там такого. http://prntscr.com/i7kehk !!!! смотрю в пример http://prntscr.com/i7kf6f и мне скрывает все точки, но мне же нужно показать начало и конец, просто подумав, не читая ни чего я добавил wayPointVisible: false,  wayPointStartVisible: true, wayPointFinishVisible: true, и вуаля, прячет все кроме начала и конца, только вот ни в примере ни в доках этого не найти. Как вы думаете это нормально????

Comment: Как вы правильно заметили, тут https://prnt.sc/i7kehk указаны _префиксы_ опций, среди которых есть и `wayPointStart`. Сами опции такие же как для соответствующих геометрий, в данном случае [точек](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/Placemark-docpage/?from=SO#param-options.visible).

Если ответ вам помог, вы можете отметить его как правильный. Если у вас есть фидбек на документацию  API, его лучше оставить техподдержке сервиса [здесь](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/geocoder/desc/feedback/troubleshooting-docpage/?from=SO#feedback)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй при создании мультимаршрута добавь опцию

```
editorMidPointsType: 'via'
```

(да, в документации маленькая ошибочка). Затем добавляй или редактируй точки через

`multiRoute.editor.start({ addMidPoints: true, dragWayPoints: false, dragViaPoints: true });`

ох, как я тебя сейчас понимаю. У меня у самого сейчас так пригорает от документации. Посмотрел скрины в комментариях к ответу @Reni и мое безумие заворковало.
Может у тебя тоже была проблема в этом. У меня создавались не транзитные точки, а путевые точки.