# Yandex maps API Multiroute -> 'pedestrian'. Маркеры с расстоянием - как их удалить?

Tags: яндекс-карты

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Из документации яндекс API:
Транзитная точка — точка, через которую нужно проложить маршрут, но в которой не подразумевается остановка. Транзитные точки поддерживаются только для автомобильной маршрутизации. Для пешей маршрутизации можем работать лишь только через 'wayPoints'.

Интересно, а как у оставшихся для пешего маршрута НЕтранзитных точек убрать маркеры с расстоянием

```
    <script src = "http://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?load=package.full&lang=ru-RU" type = "text/javascript"></script>    
    <script src = "http://yandex.st/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"                 type = "text/javascript"></script>

    <script type = "text/javascript">

        ymaps.ready ( function init () {        
        myMap = new ymaps.Map ( "map", { center: [ 47.025, 28.83 ], zoom: 12 } ); 
            calcRoute ([[46.9597334,28.7491257],[46.9441271,28.7769148],[46.9474754,28.7746193],[46.9721163,28.7659335]], 'unknown', '#1e98ff' );
        });

        function calcRoute ( referencePoints, name, color ) {                     
            // Создаем мультимаршрут и настраиваем его внешний вид с помощью опций.
            var multiRoute = new ymaps.multiRouter.MultiRoute({
                referencePoints: referencePoints, params: {
                routingMode: 'pedestrian'}, {
                wayPointVisible:false,                  
                routeWalkMarkerVisible: false,
                 pinVisible:false,
                 pinHasBalloon:false,
                 pinHasHint:false,
                routeActiveStrokeColor: color,
                boundsAutoApply: true
            });

                // Добавление маршрута на карту.
                myMap.geoObjects.add(multiRoute);                   
        }
```

Вопрос обсуждался уже, и даже были даны на него ответы. Но они не учитывают факт, что в маршруте типа 'pedestrian' не удастся выкрутиться при помощи 'viaPoint'

Ссылка на имеющуюся на эту тему дискуссию:
[Как скрыть маркеры с расстоянием для пешеходного мультимаршрута](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/777513/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B-%D1%81-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%88%D1%80%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B0).

masstransit - не предлагать. Он не показывает дорожку от точки к точке, а только отображает маркеры:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нашёл сам ответ на свой вопрос.

routeActiveMarkerVisible: false - вот так всё просто. Очень грустно что такой элементарной вещи не оказалось в документации к API Яндекс карт. А если оно там и есть, то хочу обратить внимание создателей документации к API на её неинформативность. Я с большим трудом нашёл это решение тут:
https://yandex.ru/blog/mapsapi/54243

а за одно и

routeOpenBalloonOnClick: false - чтоб отключить балун который появляется при клике на маршруте.

Comment: ловите плюс за `routeOpenBalloonOnClick`